# Uninstall core forum.module while keeping content type and taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm upgrading a site from D5 to D7 and have a large amount of forum posts. However, I no longer want to use the core forum module, instead using views...

When I disable the module, I lose access to the "Forum Post" content type that the module creates. Also, Drupal doesn't have "ownership" of the "Forums" taxonomy.

On the plus side, the content remains. However, I can no longer add new "Forum Post" content and, since the forum module isn't enabled, I can't even create automatic aliases for the "Forum" taxonomy.

Is my only option to run through node_convert, and hope for the best? Or is there a few things I can manually edit in the DB that would give me full ownership of the content type and taxonomy (as if I had created them from scratch and never installed the module in the fist place)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no simple thing like "content type ownership". There is `module` column in `{node_type}` table, but simply changing it to "node" (as set for handmade content types) might not be enough. Forum module implements node-related hooks, and integrity of forum data might be endangered if you will simply turn them off and change module in database.

Safer option would be to export data you need to some neutral format, like XML, and then use Feeds or similar module to import it again, to the content type created with your new needs in mind.

Comment: Thanks, Molot. I figured that was the case, just had hoped that a  core module wouldn't be so aggressive. This was my first Drupal site and had I been more experienced, I wouldn't have used core forum. 

I hadn't considered using feeds to do an import which might be fine. I'll give node_convert a shot first and see what happens.

Comment: @Kirk Sorry to disappoint. There was just too many hooks to figure. node convert should be fine, but as always: **there is no such thing as too much backups** :)